# microk8s - deploy application not working

Tags: kubernetes

I have problem with my app. I have server where i have microk8s and i trying deploy application. I writed deploy, ingress and service file.
deploy.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-nginx
          image: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: learn-linux.eu
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: learn-linux.eu
      http:
          paths:
            - path: /
              backend:
                  serviceName: nginx-service
                  servicePort: 80
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
  labels:
    app: my-nginx
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: my-nginx
```

Domain record A is changed to server IP where i have microk8s. But when i execute curl learn-linux.eu i getting:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused

but when i execute curl command to pod IP, i receive nginx default page

```
root@learn-linux:~# curl 10.1.31.22
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

My service describe:

```
Name:              nginx-service
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=my-nginx
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=my-nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.152.183.44
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         <none>
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

**microk8s kubectl describe deployments my-nginx**

```
Name:                   my-nginx
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 03 Sep 2020 12:18:15 +0200
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               run=my-nginx
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=my-nginx
  Containers:
   my-nginx:
    Image:        nginx
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   my-nginx-5dc4865748 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
root@learn-linux:~# microk8s kubectl describe deployments my-nginx
Name:                   my-nginx
Namespace:              default
CreationTimestamp:      Thu, 03 Sep 2020 12:18:15 +0200
Labels:                 <none>
Annotations:            deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: 1
Selector:               run=my-nginx
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable
StrategyType:           RollingUpdate
MinReadySeconds:        0
RollingUpdateStrategy:  25% max unavailable, 25% max surge
Pod Template:
  Labels:  run=my-nginx
  Containers:
   my-nginx:
    Image:        nginx
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
  Volumes:        <none>
Conditions:
  Type           Status  Reason
  ----           ------  ------
  Available      True    MinimumReplicasAvailable
  Progressing    True    NewReplicaSetAvailable
OldReplicaSets:  <none>
NewReplicaSet:   my-nginx-5dc4865748 (1/1 replicas created)
Events:          <none>
```

**microk8s kubectl describe pod my-nginx-5dc4865748**

```
Name:         my-nginx-5dc4865748-nbjww
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         learn-linux/193.33.111.185
Start Time:   Thu, 03 Sep 2020 12:18:16 +0200
Labels:       pod-template-hash=5dc4865748
              run=my-nginx
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.1.31.22
IPs:
  IP:           10.1.31.22
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/my-nginx-5dc4865748
Containers:
  my-nginx:
    Container ID:   containerd://a15250412d4ce90ed9d5d31f98aff233cbe88bf26378429f6521e26a979281a2
    Image:          nginx
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/nginx@sha256:b0ad43f7ee5edbc0effbc14645ae7055e21bc1973aee5150745632a24a752661
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 03 Sep 2020 12:18:32 +0200
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-2wkwf (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-2wkwf:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-2wkwf
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

I don't know what i do wrong, i tried from many tutorials but still not working. Anyone have idea?

#Update
**microk8s kubectl get ingress**

```
NAME             CLASS    HOSTS            ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
learn-linux.eu   <none>   learn-linux.eu             80      15h
```

**curl -v -H "host: learn-linux.eu" 10.1.31.24**

```
*   Trying 10.1.31.24:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.1.31.24 (10.1.31.24) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: learn-linux.eu
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.19.2
< Date: Fri, 04 Sep 2020 07:37:38 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 612
< Last-Modified: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 14:50:35 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< ETag: "5f32b03b-264"
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
    body {
        width: 35em;
        margin: 0 auto;
        font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to nginx!</h1>
<p>If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and
working. Further configuration is required.</p>

<p>For online documentation and support please refer to
<a href="http://nginx.org/">nginx.org</a>.<br/>
Commercial support is available at
<a href="http://nginx.com/">nginx.com</a>.</p>

<p><em>Thank you for using nginx.</em></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you use ingress microk8s [addon](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-ingress)? Can you add output from `kubectl get ingress`? Can you add output from `curl -v -H "host: learn-linux.eu" ingress-ip/`?

Comment: @Jakub added :)

Comment: curl -v shows that it works, so the problem here is a host. In minikube you would add a record in `/etc/hosts` with nginx-ingress ip, there is [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/#create-an-ingress-resource) about that. not sure if this will work microk8s. Could you try it?

Comment: @Jakub yes i added. Now when i execute curl on server i got response from nginx, but when i go to page url learn-linux.eu/ not working

Comment: Do you have [dns addon](https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-dns) installed? You're trying to enter the page on server or on you'r local pc?

Comment: @Jakub yes "Addon dns is already enabled." Yes i trying to enter the page but not working. Working only from server where i have k8s